# Setting mouse wheel zooms in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, mouse-wheel

How do I set mouse wheel zooms in ArcMap 10.1?

We want zooming in ArcMap to work like it does in OpenLayers.

Answer (score 9):

From the online help for [Quick ways to navigate data frames and layouts](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00660000043z000000):

> You can reverse the zoom in/zoom out convention used by the mouse
>   wheel. Click Customize > ArcMap Options to open the ArcMap Options
>   dialog box. Click the General tab and make your changes in the Mouse Wheel and Continuous Zoom/Pan Tool section.

Answer (score 1):

To change your Mouse/Scroll settings with Zoom In/ Zoom Oot:

- Click on the Customize > ArcMap Options > General.
- Go Down to the bottom to where is says "Mouse Wheel and Continuous Zoom/Pan Tool".
- Click on / Enable "Zoom In".

[image: CUSTOMIZE Tab]
[image: ARCMAP OPTIONS Tab]
[image: Click on / Enable ZOOM IN]